# Piping functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, pipeline

I worked on pretty good number of functions like given below

```
function a(declara,callback) {
   x = declara.x;
   y = declara.y;
   return callback.call(this,[declara]);
}

a({x:1,y:2},function(){ console.log(x+" , "+y); });
```

but I found thats not actually what callback does, could you please explain me, how can a piping structure be implemented as follows:

```
a({x:1,y:2}).print()
```

(Something similar to what jQuery does, also kindly explain me the same!)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, then

```
function a(declara) {
   x = declara.x;
   y = declara.y;
   return {print:function(){ console.log(x+" , "+y); }}; //return an object whose one key-value has function inside of it.
}

a({x:1,y:2}).print();
```

Comment: might as well remove `callback` argument